# Setting ng-click in ng-repeat dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a lot of data within ng-repeat. It looks like table with many rows and columns. I want to put `ng-click` directive on some of cell of table.

Can i put some condition before `ng-click` directive? If this condition is true - I want to put the directive, otherwise - not to put.

Comment: you can always put `ng-click` but neutralize it with a `ng-disabled`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just put the directive in there and pass it a condition as a parameter which returns boolean. In the directive compile function check if your parameter is right and decide from there what you load.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you were looking for?

```
<ul class="menuItems">
            <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
                <div ng-if="item.type == 'link' ">
                    <a href="item.url" title="item.description">{{item.name}}</a>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="item.type == 'function' ">
                    <span ng-click="function(item.command)" title="item.description">{{item.name}}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```